# Validating List Object Value

Tags: c#

```
List<string> SampleList = new List<string>();
string tmpStr = "MyStringValue";
```

From this example, how to check the value of the string variable `tmpStr` if it's already in `SampleList`?

Comment: But I voted up for both of you! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`List<T>.Contains Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx)

```
if (SampleList.Contains(tmpStr))
{
    //  list already contains this value
}
else
{
    // the list does not already contain this value
}
```

If your objective is to prevent your list from containing duplicate elements at all times then you might consider using the [`HashSet<T> Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) which does not allow for duplicate values.

Comment: Oh ".Contains" is the key then. Thank you. I'm, totally new to List object.

Comment: Can you give me an example on how to use this HashSet<T> Class to my List?

Comment: @ChrisN.P. Here is a link to a comprehensive (much more so than I could be) beginners' tutorial: http://www.dotnetperls.com/hashset

Comment: Thanks. Let me check this then :)

Comment: Can I do this: var hash = new HashSet<List>(SampleList)?

Comment: @ChrisN.P. No worries. Would you consider accepting my answer?

Comment: Both of you provided me a great answer and I can't pick any. Since both approach works.

Comment: Alright I decided to select your's for posting your solution first. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Any particular reason for using `List`?

You can use a Set, `Set<string> hs = new HashSet<string>();` and it will `not allow duplicates`.

```
Set<string> hs = new HashSet<string>();
hs.add("String1");
hs.add("String2");
hs.add("String3");

// Now if you try to add String1 again, it wont add, but return false.
hs.add("String1");
```

**If you do not want duplicates for case insensitive elements use**

```
HashSet<string> hs = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I used List to store all the items from the database.

Comment: Can I apply this approach to a List?

Comment: @ChrisN.P. With approach do you mean by not allowing duplicates?

Comment: Yes the one that you posted.

Comment: Set will be useful if you do not want duplicates. HashMap will be useful if you need to associate key-value pairs, for example, say String, and the occurrence of the String in the database. So it all depends on your use.

Comment: I think I want to use this HashSet. Can you provide me an example on how to apply this to my list?

Comment: @ChrisN.P. Edited the code. The link by ByteBlast should also help you.

Comment: Wow this is cool. both your's and ByteBlast works for me! You've been very helpful as well. Thank you guys!

Comment: Thank you for your help JNP. I have to marked ByteBlast's post since he posted it first but both of you really helped me a lot!

Comment: Hoping to see answers from you for my future queries. Thanks and cheers!